# Java currency symbol rendering

Tags: java, swing, fonts, currency, formatter

I've a JTable that contains prices with currency symbols. When I show my table all the currency symbol are well formatted.

Then I try to change the table font and when I try apply the new font the yen symbol is not rendered.

```
Font newFont = new Font(name, style, size);
getDataTable().setFont(newFont);
```

Comment: Which font? I would say that the font you want does not have the yen symbol therefore it can't display it

Comment: Does the new font have the glyph for the yen symbol?

Comment: Original Font = Tahoma, New Font = Times new roman, for example.

Comment: If I try, for test, to apply Tahoma as new font, I've the same error.

Comment: Do you use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` to format the values with currency style?

Comment: Each cell table show a JLabel with a simple string, currencySymbol + value.
Using `java.util.Currency` I've obtained the currency symbol from a specific locale.
I've different currencies in the same table.